# Vue - Best way to poll the same API endpoint for multiple components simultaneously

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I need to fetch continuously updating API endpoint data for several components on my NUXT site, 2 of which are visible simultaneously at any given moment. I wonder what is the best practice to poll the same endpoint for several different components visible at the same time?

Currently, I am using VUEX to send the API data to my components and then using setInterval with a refresh function to update the data in each component. This is clearly a clumsy solution (I am a beginner). I was thinking about polling the API directly in VUEX but I understand this is not advisable either.

This is my current (clumsy) solution:

VUEX:

```
// STATE - Initial values
export const state = () => ({
  content: {}
});


// ACTIONS 
export const actions = {
    async nuxtServerInit ({ commit }) {
        const response = await this.$axios.$get('https://public.radio.net/stations/see15310/status');
        commit('setContent', response)
    }
}

// MUTATIONS 
export const mutations = {
    setContent(state, content) {
      state.content = content;
    }
  }
```

And in each component:

```
    computed: {
    content () {
      return this.$store.state.content
    },

    methods: {
      refresh() {
        this.$nuxt.refresh()
      }
    },

    mounted() {
      window.setInterval(() => {
        this.refresh();
      }, 5000);
```

Comment: The proper solution for your use-case is setting up [SSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) on server. Your app subscribes to it and commits on each received event. Any rendered component reacts to the state change. This way, if no change happens for 2 days, nothing happens in your app. And if you get an event every second, you're not missing any of them.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it's a normal solution to do the polling in vuex. **Vuex is your application state** and the **one source of truth** for all dependant components. And if you need to update some similar state for different components - it's a rational solution to do it in vuex action.

Another solution could be the event bus. [First article about it from google](https://dev.to/lilianaziolek/how-to-build-a-simple-event-bus-in-vue-nuxt-592)

Also, I don't recommend use **SetInterval** for polling. Because it's don't wait of async operation ending. This fact could shoot you in the foot, if a client has network delay or another glitch. I used **SetTimeout** for this purpose.

```js
async function getActualData() {
  // get data from REST API
}

async function doPolling() {
  const newData = await getActualData() // waiting of finish of async function
  // update vuex state or send update event to event bus

  setTimeout(doPolling, 5000)
}

doPolling()
```

If my answer missed into your question, then give me more details please. What is the problem you want to solve? And what disadvantages do you see in your(by your words ;) ) "clumsy" solution?

Comment: I tried implementing your solution to my code but it does not return anything to the state: 

`export const actions = {
    async nuxtServerInit() {
        const response = await this.$axios.$get('https://api.com');
    return response
    },
  

     async doPolling({ commit }) {
      const newData = await nuxtServerInit()
    commit('setContent', newData)
      setTimeout(doPolling, 5000)
      

      doPolling() 
    },
     
  }`

Comment: I also tried this, but again empty object returned to state:
`export const actions = {
    async nuxtServerInit( {commit }) {
        const response = await this.$axios.$get('https://api.com/example');
        setTimeout(() => commit('setContent', response), 3000); 

    
    }
  

  }`

Comment: You wrote your code in nuxtServerInit action. This code runs only once and only from the server-side [Docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store#the-nuxtserverinit-action). Check the docs and try one more time, please. If you face the problems, say to me. I try to compose the simple project in my GitHub